# Session does not get updated value in php

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am calling firstpage.php it changing $_SESSION['Progress'] session value. But when I call progress.php for get $_SESSION['Progress'] session value it keep gives "1" value. progress.php doesn't gives updated value. I checked manually firstpage.php working fine. but I don't know why progress.php doesn't give updated value.

```
var progressInterval;
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "firstpage.php",
          cache: false,
          data: {
            first: first
          },
          success:function(result)
          {
            if(progressInterval) {
                clearInterval(progressInterval); //if I remove this session still show "1" output
            }
            alert(result); // print session value. ex:- value- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,Final=8
          }
  });

  progressInterval = setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
          url:'progress.php',
          type: 'get',
          data: {"name":"Progress"},
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(data) {
              $('.output').text((parseInt(data.progress))+"%"); // KEEP SHOWING 1% (why value does not change?????)
          },
          error:function(err){
              console.log(err);
          }
      });

  }, 1000);
```

firstpage.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Progress'] = 0;
  $data=0;
  $progress=$_SESSION['Progress'];
  foreach($album_data as $row) //assume foreach works fine.
    {
        $progress++;
        $_SESSION['Progress'] = $progress;
        $data.=$progress.",";
        session_write_close();
    }
  }
  echo $data." final=".$_SESSION['Progress']; //output-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 final=8
```

progress.php code

```
session_start();

getProgress($_GET['name']);

function getProgress($filename) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$filename])) {
        echo json_encode(array("progress" => $_SESSION[$filename]));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("progress" => 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: show us how did you set the session in `firstpage.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_write_close();` ends the current session and store session data.

At each iteration of the loop you will need to restart the session using `session_start();`

Comment: Sorry I already added `session_start()` in the starting line but I forgot to mansion in code. in firstpage.php session works fine. it also gives the output. but I didn't get from progress.php page

Comment: but what are you doing with `$filename` I didnt get that part?

Comment: nothing but I am just trying to get the value of `$_SESSION['Progress']`. And i thing It should be give.

Comment: If I reomove `clearInterval(progressInterval);` I still give me output `1`

Comment: @user3730347 remove that line `session_write_close();`

Comment: on removing `session_write_close();` session prints `8` output

Comment: But I want to show progress(like progress bar). I want to print in increasing session value.

Comment: computers are very fast, trust me 8 iterations could be done much quicker than less then a second, add `sleep(1);` at the bottom of the loop and you will notice the progess

Comment: iteration is a big code. I just show you the session part. In iteration uses copy() function and it work fine. iteration takes a long time more then 10 second.

Comment: try adding the sleep statement

Comment: `echo json_encode(array("progress" => 0, "time" => date("d-m-Y h:i:s")));` @user3730347

Comment: I added it. It didn't work. I try to inspect element. and the status of progress.php is "pending" when the firstpage.php process done then process.php return the output

Comment: are you available for chat

Comment: solved the error. we need to start every time the session(). I answered the problem check.

Comment: yes that's why I said "When you set the session you need to start the session **right before doing that** but you told me you [already did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696850/session-does-not-get-updated-value-in-php/25697369?noredirect=1#comment40165550_25696944)

Comment: @meta Ok. change the answer properly (firstpage.php). I will accept your answer

Comment: @user3730347 ok I fixed it , I upvoted both your question and your answer as well `;)`

Answer (score 2):

I changed in firstpage.php. and it works now.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Progress'] = 0;
 $data=0;
  $progress=$_SESSION['Progress'];
  foreach($album_data as $row) //assume foreach works fine.
   {
    session_start(); //we need to start session because we closed the session using session_write_close(); 
    $progress++;
    $_SESSION['Progress'] = $progress;
    $data.=$progress.",";
    session_write_close(); // need to close because we getting the value uses at progress.php. 
   }
 }
 session_start();
 echo $data." final=".$_SESSION['Progress']; //output-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 final=8
```

Comment: No we need to start every time

Answer (score 0):

You migh try this. you have index.php which fetch value of `$_SESSION['Progress']` here is what index.php contain

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var progressInterval;

        progressInterval = setInterval( function(){
        $.ajax({
              url: "progress.php",
              data: { name: 1 }
            }).done(function(msg) {
               $("#test1").text(msg);
            });
        }, 2000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id='test1' class='output'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

it will fetch all `$_SESSION['Progress']` every 2 seconds.

And here what **progress.php** contain

```
session_start();
getProgress($_GET['name']);
function getProgress($filename) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['Progress'])) {
        echo json_encode(array("progress" => $_SESSION['Progress']));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("progress" => 0));
    }
}
```

and then for **firstpage.php**

```
session_start();
  $_SESSION['Progress'] = 0;
  /*
  $data=0;
  $progress=$_SESSION['Progress'];
  foreach($album_data as $row) //assume foreach works fine.
    {
        $progress++;
        $_SESSION['Progress'] = $progress;
        $data.=$progress.",";
        session_write_close();
    }
  }
  echo $data." final=".$_SESSION['Progress']; //output-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 final=8
  */
```

firstpage.php work just for change `$_SESSION['Progress']` value.

Try to open 2 windows of browser. one for index.php and one for firstpage.php.

Keep index.php open, while you change the value of `$_SESSION['Progress']` in firstpage.php to 2(for example) and reload page `firstpage.php`. then, you will found out the value of `$_SESSION['Progress']`which return by ajax request in `index.php` change to `{"progress":2}`

**So your problem I think on performing ajax request.**

Comment: I think the problem is `session locking`in firstpage.php page. I try to inspect element. and the status of progress.php is "pending" when the firstpage.php process done then process.php return the output

Comment: I Guest so. I think you should extend your get session request interval and make sure set session request called first using window.onload or document.onload to call get session ajax request.